# angular - After installing angular-resource and importing in @NgModule throws $$minErr undefined error

Tags: angular, angular-resource

I am trying to use $resource object in my project. These are the steps I followed to install and import the package.

1. Installed angular-resource using npm - npm install angular-resource
2. Added ngResource as dependency in @NgModule - require('angular-resource')

Versions:

- angular-resource - 1.7.5
- @angular/cli     - 7.0

Compiles fine. When running, throws the following error

***Cannot read property '$$minErr' of undefined***

It's complaining that it can't find angular.js file so unable to find that property. I created my project with Angular CLI and never needed to install angular separately and never used script tag for angular.

I am assuming CLI stores angular in a different folder structure?
What am I missing here?

***UPDATE***

```
declare var require: any;  
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';  
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';  
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';    
import { ActivityListComponent } from './activities/activity-list.component';   

@NgModule({    

declarations: [
AppComponent,
ActivityListComponent],  

imports: [
BrowserModule,  
require('angular-resource')],    

providers: [],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]})    

export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Can you provide app.module.ts ..?

Comment: @IsankaThalagala Edited the post with app.module.ts. The last error is thrown when I added require['angular'].

Answer (score 1):

I think that 'angular-resource' package is for angularJS https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-resource  .

If you wanna use angular resource for angular 2+, you can use angular-material instead of angular-resource.it includes most of components we often use. https://material.angular.io/components/categories

> npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk @angular/animations

Try this steps:
https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started

Comment: The last url takes me back to npm install page. Can you please update it?

Comment: I have updated last URL. If you think this is the right solution for your matter, mark this as the answer for future users.